# c++ _bstr_t instead of use string

Tags: c++, string, com, bstr

I have some code to read file,but it is used std::string, i need to use  _bstr_t
the code follow can works fine. how to change the type?

```
   std::ifstream inFile("QdatPassWordconfig.config");
  std::string sPassWord; //(here, i need to use _bstr_t)
  std::string sTemp;
  if (inFile.is_open())
  {
      if(std::getline(inFile,sTemp)) 
      {
            cout<<sTemp<<endl;
            sPassWord=sTemp;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [`_bstr_t` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), you will see that its [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bh2f8sk.aspx) takes a normal `const char *`.

So it's probably just to assign to it:

```
_bstr_t sPassword;

// ...

sPassword = sTemp.c_str();
```

---

If you have trouble using normal narrow-character strings, you should convert all your code relating to this to use wide-character string, i.e. the classes with the `w` prefix:

```
std::wifstream inFile("QdatPassWordconfig.config");
_bstr_t sPassword;
std::wstring sTemp;

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    if(std::getline(inFile, sTemp)) 
    {
        std::wcout << sTemp << endl;

        sPassword = sTemp.c_str();
    }
}
```

Comment: if sTemp="123", but only if the sTeml=L"123",then can work fine.how to add "L"?

Comment: @jack.li You might have to use the wide-character functions and classes.

Comment: I am new with c++, so i don't know how to use wide-character to read file or write file?

Comment: see my read and write file with std::string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080652/c-get-one-line-data-in-txt-file

Comment: @jack.li Write wide-character strings as well? Or use narrow-character, and convert to wide-character strings when needed. If you wait a little I will _try_ to come up with some code for that.